# How to invalidate a useMutation react-query

Tags: react-query

inside a project we are using a POST request (implemented with the `useMutation` from `react-query`) in order to obtain data, as if it were a GET request (for several reasons, I know it's not standard compliant). We would like to invalidate these requests after others, as it is possible to do with GETs (using `queryClient.invalidateQueries()` ) to make then re-run.

We tried to add the endpoints to the invalidation function, but they does not re-run.

Comment: Why not use `useQuery` even if it is a POST request?

Comment: You are actually right. I was working with an old version and I haven't thought about changing it. Thank you, it works!